# How do I pass a message from an object to another object in Free Pascal

Tags: lazarus, freepascal, destroy

I have a form and then I have a 'TPageControl' object (named 'MyPages') and a 'TButton' object (named 'MyButton') placed on it at **design time**. 
Then I have a new class called 'TTab' which extends 'TTabSheet'. 'TTab' class has a 'TButton' object as one of its member variables like below.

```
class TTab = class(TTabSheet)
private
  m_btnCloseTab: TButton;
end;
```

When I click on the 'MyButton', it would create a new 'TTab' object, init the tab (like instantiating the 'm_btnCloseTab') and add it to 'MyPages' at **run time**.

```
Procedure TForm1.MyButtonClick(Sender:TObject);
var
  newTab: TTab;
  newCaption: AnsiString;
begin
  newCaption:= 'Tab' + IntToStr(count); //count is a global var
  inc(count);

  newTab:= TTab.Create(nil);
  newTab.Init(newCaption);
  newTab.Parent(MyPages);
end;
```

This is what the TTab.Init(newCaption: AnsiString) Procedure looks like.

```
Procedure TTab.Init(newCaption: AnsiString);
begin
  Self.Caption:= newCaption;
  m_btnCloseTab:= TButton.Create(nil);
  with m_btnCloseTab do begin
    Parent:= Self;
    Left:= 10;
    Top:= 10;
    Caption:= 'Close Tab';
    Visible:= True;
    OnClick:= @closeTab;
  end;
end;
```

That adds a new tab alright. The close button is also shown on each tab.

How do I click on the 'm_btnCloseTab' on each tab to close that particular tab?

If I define a destructor (by overriding the destructor of the TTabSheet) for TTab like below, I can call it from outside.

```
Destructor TTab.Destroy;
begin
  if m_btnCloseTab <> nil then begin
    m_btnCloseTab.Destroy;
    m_btnCloseTab:= nil;
  end;
  inherited;
end;
```

But I cannot call the Destructor from inside the tab (well, you can). If I do it, I cannot free the m_btnCloseTab object as it would give an exception, because we are still its event handler. If I don't free it, the tab gets closed fine, but the memory gets leaked (because we did not free m_btnCloseTab).

I believe I have to trigger an event so that the destructor can be called from the outside of 'TTab'. I don't know how to do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand everything correctly. But if you create the m_btnCloseTab with the Tab as its owner (mbtn_CloseTab := TButton.Create(self), instead of ...Create(nil)) then the button is automatically destroyed along with the tab. Also, the TTab should have a Notification method which is called whenever one of its children is destroyed and which you can use to set mbtn_CloseTab to nil: This would avoid that Tab calls the buttons's destructor in the case that the buttons has been destroyed before for some reason.

Comment: Thank you for the comment (I thought nobody used Free Pascal anymore) but it does not make a difference to the actual result.

By using create(nil), I have to free the m_btnCloseTab by myself inside the destructor. By using Create(Self), the destructor of the TTab class does it automatically.

What is a notification method? How do I implement one? That I think is what I need to do, kind of like a Delegate function in C#. Appreciate it if you could point me towards a tutorial or documentation on how to do it.

Comment: You are wrong. Visit the Lazarus forum to see an alive Pascal community.

Comment: My bad. I meant to say 'nobody here'.

Answer (score 0):

You can find Notification methods all over the LCL sources (and in Delphi as well, of course). A simple example is a TLabeledEdit: this is some kind of "TEdit" which contains a TLabel. If the Label is destroyed the LabeledEdit is notified of this because it must set the reference to the label to nil. Otherwise the destructor of TLabeledEdit would attempt to destroy the label again - BOOM. Here the method is like this (pasted from ExtCtrls):

```
procedure TCustomLabeledEdit.Notification(AComponent: TComponent;
  Operation: TOperation);
begin
  inherited Notification(AComponent, Operation);
  if (AComponent = FEditLabel) and (Operation = opRemove) then
    FEditLabel := nil;
end;
```

And here you can see what you have to do in your case:

```
procedure TTab.Notification(AComponent: TComponent;
  Operation: TOperation);
begin
  inherited Notification(AComponent, Operation);
  if (AComponent = m_BtnCloseTab) and (Operation = opRemove) then
    m_BtnCloseTab := nil;
end;
```

Please note that Notification is a virtual method and must be declared with the attribute "override" in the protected section of the component.

Comment: It still crashes when Destroy is called from the m_BtnCloseTab's onClick event hander.

I'm trying to understand what Notification does exactly. 

What event triggers a call to Notification? Notification procedure was called many times, right from the point where I started creating a new tab to the actual killing. 

    m_BtnCloseTab := nil;

was only called right before crashing. Crashing means, I get the following error: 

    Project project1 raised exception class 'External: SIGSEGV'. 
    At address 40CDA8

Comment: Is the owner of the button still nil? I could image that an object being destroyed must notify its owner because this is the object which will destroy it in the end. But if the owner is nil there's nobody to be notified...  -- Notification extends deeply into the heart of the LCL (VCL) and is introduced by TComponent. For operation opRemove it is called whenever a TComponent is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a single button for this task.

Take m_btnCloseTab declaration out of TTab and put it in private main form.

Then on your main form's FormCreate:

m_btnCloseTab := TButton.Create( MyPages );

(the above assumes MyPages is a component placed on the form, if not it must be created first.)

Give the button a top and left that makes sense for your TTab's.

Now m_btnCloseTab will be freed when MyPages is freed which is freed when the form is closed.

Now all you have to do is create your new tabs as you like and when one is focused simply make that tab the parent of your button. You could do this, for instance, in the MyPages OnChange method or whatever it has like that.

When the button is clicked it does something like TTab( Parent ).Free;

However, you may need to store Parent in a local variable in the button's OnClick, say:

TempTab: TTab

Then simply set TempTab := TTab( Parent ), set Button's Parent to nil, then call TempTab.Free;

I would also give your Tabs an owner. That way if the user closes the form with tabs still open (that is, your button hasn't been clicked) the owner will free them.

So declare your tabs like:

newTab:= TTab.Create( MyPages );

This should solve all your problems and, after a bit of fiddling, is quite easy to manage.

One final recommendation I would use the method .Free and/or FreeAndNil( ) rather than calling .destroy directly.

Comment: That's a good idea. I'll try it out when I have some free time. 

For the time being, in my actual project, I found a workaround. Instead of freeing the tabs, I just remove them from the TPageControl by settings the TTab.PageControl:= nil when the tab close button is clicked. 

It is not a big issue in my application because the number of tabs are finite, and those tabs are anyway kept in a list which will be freed when the main form is closed. I try to release as much memory as possible before 'hiding' the tabs to make the app not feel heavy.